# Show alert message in Swift 2.0 Xcode 7 when the app is in background

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, background, popup

I am currently trying to display an alert message as a pop up in my app. When the application is currently on the screen, running from foreground, it shows the popup. However, the problem is that when the application is running in the background, the popup is not displayed on iOS. It is only shown when the user enters back into the app.

Here is the popup source code:

```
func popupDeAlerta(){
    // Dismiss Message
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert title", message:
        "alert message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert) 

    AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)) // vibration

    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler: nil))
    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is the right behavior , Alert view controller shows alert only on that controller in which it is added like :

```
alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler: nil))
    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

IF you want an action which is automatically alert you after some time , You have to implement notifications in your App.

[Notifications Link Here](https://developer.apple.com/notifications/)

Comment: The best way that I have found until now:
On Appdelegate.swif there is a pre-defined function:

  func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
}

Ive added the following code:

  let notification = UILocalNotification()
  notification.alertAction = "Title Message"
  notification.alertBody = "Body Message"
  notification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 5)
  notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
  notification.category = "INVITE_CATEGORY";
UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)

Answer (score 0):

The best way that I have found until now. If someone has other suggestions or can discuss further it is very welcome.
On Appdelegate.swif there is a pre-defined function called "applicationDidEnterBackground". Just did it this way:

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {

let notification = UILocalNotification() 
notification.alertAction = "Title Message" 
notification.alertBody = "Body Message" 
notification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 5) 
notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName 
notification.category = "INVITE_CATEGORY"; 
UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification) }
```